# The object doesn't get persisted in Hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, persistence

I configured Hibernate and Spring.

The config and Java class:

```
package com.dao.impl;

import com.dao.IPersonRepository;
import com.dao.impl.generic.GenericRepository;
import com.model.Person;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/18/2015.
 */
@Repository
public class PersonRepository extends GenericRepository<Person, Long> implements IPersonRepository {

}


package com.dao;


import com.dao.iGeneric.IGenericRepository;
import com.model.Person;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/18/2015.
 */
public interface IPersonRepository extends IGenericRepository<Person, Long> {
}


package com.dao.iGeneric;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/23/2015.
 */
public abstract interface IGenericRepository<T, pk extends Serializable> {
    public void save(T t);

    public T loadByEntityId(pk id);
}




package com.dao.impl.generic;

import com.dao.iGeneric.IGenericRepository;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/23/2015.
 */
@Repository
public class GenericRepository<T, pk extends Serializable> implements IGenericRepository<T, pk> {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Object o) {
        getSession().save(o);
    }

    @Override
    public T loadByEntityId(pk id) {
        Session session = getSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person e where e.id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return ((T) query.uniqueResult());
    }
}
```

xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:oracle-hibernate.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

   <!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="test" />-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql"> ${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema"> ${hibernate.default_schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop> <!--Oracle need -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF8</prop> <!--Oracle need -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF8</prop> <!--Oracle need -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useEncoding">true</prop> <!--Oracle need -->
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" >${hibernate.transaction.factory_class}</prop>
               <!-- <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" >${hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" >${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>-->

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                          proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

personService:

```
package com.service.impl;

import com.dao.IPersonRepository;
import com.model.Person;
import com.service.IPersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/15/2015.
 */
@Service
public class PersonService implements IPersonService {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private IPersonRepository iPersonRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertPerson(Person person) {
        iPersonRepository.save(person);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void loadByEntityId(Long id) {
        Person person = iPersonRepository.loadByEntityId(id);
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        person.setName("matin");

    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jpa lib-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

My problem:
```

In Hibernate the Object Model has 3 states:
1- Transient 
2- Persistent 
3- Detached

I want to clarify the following situation:

When Object Model is fetched from the DataBase, it is Persistent. In loadByEntityId of PersonService when the Person Entity is loaded, It isn't persistent. **Why?**
I changed name to 'Matin' but didn't commited to DataBase.

Comment: Alright i would like to know what is your question/problem ?

Comment: @PawełGłowacz, his point is "When Object Model is fetched from the DataBase, it is Persistent.

In loadByEntityId of PersonService when the Person Entity is loaded, It isn't persistent."

Comment: I want to see a proper question in his post. Nothing more.

Comment: Don't open a session. Change your getSession to only call `getCurrentSession` if you use `openSession` you are opening an unmanaged and uncontrolled session. If you get an exception after the change it means your transactional setup is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**:

Thanks to *M. Deinum* for explain subtle differences.

Please remove this method:

```
private Session getSession() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

and just invoke `getCurrentSession()` for example:

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

In this method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void loadByEntityId(Long id) {
    Person person = iPersonRepository.loadByEntityId(id);
    System.out.println(person.getName());
    person.setName("matin");

}
```

you have found `Person` entity and it's pretty much done. Under the hood you are using `session` in `Hibernate` so this particular code:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Person e where e.id=:id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    return ((T) query.uniqueResult());
```

only retrieve data.

What you need to do is define `update` method in your repository `IGenericRepository` interface:

```
public abstract interface IGenericRepository<T, pk extends Serializable> {
    public void save(T t);
    public T loadByEntityId(pk id);
    public void updateEntity(T t);
}
```

implement it in `GenericRepository`:

```
@Override
public void updateEntity(T entity) {
    getSession().update(entity);
}
```

define in `IPersonService` method `updatePerson` and implement it in `PersonService` and use `updateEntity` from Repostitory:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updatePerson(Person person) {
    iPersonRepository.updateEntity(person);
}
```

And now when you use `loadByEntityId` after you have updated `Person` with `updatePerson` you should retrieve updated entity from db.

Comment: Well  actually no. If you retrieve a managed instance from hibernate and change that, hibernate will automatically sync that with the database (as long as it is within a single transaction).

Comment: Because he is using an unmanaged session, which never gets flushed/committed. Hence nothing will ever be persisted... Your solution would make it work but also make it worse with yet another session. Eventually leading to pool starvation because connections will not be closed.

Comment: He marked method with `@Transactional` and defined `transactionManager` in spring configuration. Even his Repository is managed by spring so overall when you do `getSession().update()/save()` spring decide when to close session/and commit transaction. You can ofcourse do this manually by invoking `getSession().beginTransaction()` /*your code*/ and `getSession().getTransaction().commit()`. But he configured spring to make this automatically. So i do not understand your point now @M. Deinum

Comment: No it doesn't not when there is no session or the tx config isn't correct... Then it will do `openSession` and use a session Spring isn't aware of and it will never be committed...

Comment: Show me in his example where there is no session nor tx config is not correct ? And give me a proper one ? Im curious right now.

Comment: I only see in his example that his is opening session on `catch Exception` and this is wrong indeed and need to be changed but he is invoking `getCurrentSession()`

Comment: He should first change his `getSession` method because now it is swallowing exceptions so there is nothing to be sure. But judging from the behavior of the application (nothing committed) that is probably the case.

Comment: If there is something wrong with his tx setup you wouldn't know... Because he is catching and swallowing. Which would lead to the behavior you see now.

Comment: Alright now i understand. He need to change `getSession()` to something more subtle like just `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.